# I want to add button in page on website through div class name in js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Add button to page on  in a website through div class  in js.i tried the following code

```
 (function(){
  //  alert("heyy");
    function AddButton(){
        var site=document.querySelector(".up-form-group");
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML="Write cover letter";
        button.id="cbutton";
        button.type = "button";
        site.appendChild(button);
        console.log("added");

}
AddButton();
})();
```

But I came through this error: **append child is not a function**.
And I also tried this code below

```
document.getElementsByClassName('up-form-group')[0].appendChild(button);
```

But the error remained the same.
And another error is coming:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
If anyone can help me to solve this error

Comment: site is not `undefined` or `null` right? I mean, when you are executing this javascript code, the element `.up-form-group` should exist in the `DOM`.

Comment: yes, site exist in the DOM

Comment: I doubt the element with that class exists because your code works [as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/a4sw6ez5/). How are you calling this function?

Comment: And where from is this error coming? Even if the `.up-form-group` element doesn't exist the `site` would be assigned value of `null` by what [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#parameters) call returns when it can't find a match, at which point the error would rather be "*Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')*". The error is not in the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<div class="up-form-group"></div>` is not accessible when you call the function I suppose.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",run);    
function AddButton(){
        var site=document.querySelector(".up-form-group");;
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML="Write cover letter";
        button.id="cbutton";
        button.type = "button";
        site.appendChild(button);
        console.log("added");
}
function run(){
        AddButton();
}
```

```html
<div class="up-form-group"></div>
```